# Constructor in persistance class

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using HIbernate version 3.2.5.

I read the below line in hibernate tutorials:

`The no-argument constructor is a requirement for all persistent classes.Hibernate has to create objects for you, using Java Reflection. The constructor can be private`

This is the link for the tutorial:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html

But when I write a persistence class without a no-arg constructor, then also it works fine (I tried only retrieval part).

Hence where lies the validity of the above statement?

Please let me know if I am getting something worng.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any constructor in persistent class, JVM by default creates no-arg constructor for you, that is the reason why your code is working fine.

Read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) to understand more about constructors.